# Archive location for libudev on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, archive, udev

I currently have Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I'm trying to change my version of libudev. I'm looking for `libudev.so.0.9.3` and `libudev.so.1…` Does anyone know where archives of this library lives?

Comment: Do you mean where can you get them on the Internet or where would they be on your system?

Comment: Where they would be on the internet. But I wouldn't mind knowing where on my system they would be stored as well.

Comment: If you already have libudev of any sort installed, you can use the command `locate libudev`.  As a random note, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564709/libudev-where-is-the-source-code-repo

Comment: This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181073/ubuntu-12-04-libudev-dev-wont-install-because-of-dependencies

Comment: I tried the first link already but there was no where to download the lib file. As for the other link, it looks like they are just fixing an install problem, and I already have that version installed but want an older one if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find the package on this [site](http://pkgs.org). I searched udev or libudev and was able to download the package.