# Relocate mouse cursor on screen

Tags: python

I am using Python and PyCharm. In my script I am trying to move the mouse to the top corner of the screen ((0,0) I think).

I googled and found uinput however got this when trying to install it using:

```
sudo pip install python-uinput
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libudev.so.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

I do have libudev installed and the cosponsoring headers.

Some advice would be very appreciated!

Maybe even another simple way to move the mouse to the top left corner as I am still very inexperienced.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Which Linux distro you using? You need install [libudev](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=libudev+install). [For Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225970/1309352)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386` if you are on a debian-based distro.

Comment: Thanks for that! 
I am using Mint 16 at the moment.

SOLVED: 

Used the following: 

    from pymouse import PyMouse
    m = PyMouse()
    m.move(0, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that! I am using Mint 16 at the moment. 
SOLVED: Used the following: from pymouse import PyMouse m = PyMouse() m.move(0, 0)

To note I had to install the python-xlib

```
sudo apt-get install  python-xlib
```